# Setting a range based on values (why doesn't this code work?) with VBA/excel

Tags: excel, vba, range

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBcT5.jpg

I want to create two different ranges, one for everything on the left (column A) of the Ss in column B, and one for everything on the left of the Fs in column B. (see picture)

```
lastRowA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

Sub Test2()
    Dim rngs As Range
    Dim rngf As Range
    Dim onleft As Range

    i = 1

    Do Until i = lastRowA
        Cells(i, 2).Activate
        Select Case ActiveCell
            Case Is = "s"
                Set onleft = Cells(i, 1)
                Set rngs = Application.Union(rngs, onleft) '<error message for this line

            Case Is = "f"
                Set onleft = Cells(i, 1)
                Set rngf = Application.Union(rngf, onleft)

            Case Else
                Range("D1").Value = ":("

        End Select
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    rngs.Font.Color = RGB(123, 0, 123)
    rngf.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

End Sub
```

I would appreciate any adjustments to the code used, or any different ways of going about this problem...

The error I get is :"Invalid procedure call or arguement", Run time error 5.

I didn't use the autofilter because my motive is to use the range to count the numbers. I want to change the colours as a test to see if the code works.

Comment: It might be beneficial for you to copy the code fragment in the picture to your post, so people will be able to glance at it when opening your question (Thus giving faster judgement if they can help you or not)

Comment: Post your code here, not a link to a *picture* of your code.  Also, why do you need to do this? Why not use the Range `.AutoFilter` method and iterate `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`?

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, can you point out which line gives you the error?

Comment: @DavidZemens ive edited the question to answer your comment. I assumed there would be some obvious mistake that i missed so I didnt bother writing the error.

Comment: @Blackhawk I get the error"Invalid procedure call or arguement", Run time error 5. On the line which has been starred in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that, initially, rngs and rngf are `Nothing`, meaning it is empty and does not refer to a range.  When you try to `Union` the range onleft with `Nothing` (`rngs` or `rngf`) you get the error. The following code solves that problem:

```
Sub Test2()
    Dim rngs As Range
    Dim rngf As Range
    Dim onleft As Range

    lastRowA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    i = 1

    Do Until i = lastRowA
        Cells(i, 2).Activate
        Select Case ActiveCell
            Case Is = "s"
                Set onleft = Cells(i, 1)
                If rngs Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngs = onleft   'The first time through, rngs is nothing, so set it equal to onleft
                Else
                    Set rngs = Application.Union(rngs, onleft)  'subsequent times, the onleft is unioned with rngs
                End If

            Case Is = "f"
                Set onleft = Cells(i, 1)
                If rngf Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngf = onleft   'same thing here...
                Else
                    Set rngf = Application.Union(rngf, onleft)  '...and here
                End If

            Case Else
                Range("D1").Value = ":("

        End Select
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    rngs.Font.Color = RGB(123, 0, 123)
    rngf.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

End Sub
```